# MySQL count column from multiple tables. Group results by primary id

Tags: php, mysql, count, sum

I have the following 3 MySQL tables:

`products`

```
| id | name      | comment_count |
|----|-----------|---------------|
| 1  | Product A | 10            |
| 2  | Product B | 20            |
| 3  | Product C | 30            |
```

`products_views`

```
| product_id | pv_count | pv_date       |
| -----------|-------|------------|
| 1          | 10    | 2015-01-01 |
| 1          | 10    | 2015-01-02 |
| 1          | 10    | 2015-01-03 |
| 2          | 20    | 2015-01-01 |
| 2          | 20    | 2015-01-02 |
| 2          | 20    | 2015-01-03 |
| 3          | 30    | 2015-01-01 |
| 3          | 30    | 2015-01-02 |
| 3          | 30    | 2015-01-03 |
```

`products_likes`

```
| product_id | pl_count | pl_date       |
| -----------|-------|------------|
| 1          | 10    | 2015-01-01 |
| 1          | 10    | 2015-01-02 |
| 1          | 10    | 2015-01-03 |
| 2          | 20    | 2015-01-01 |
| 2          | 20    | 2015-01-02 |
| 2          | 20    | 2015-01-03 |
| 3          | 30    | 2015-01-01 |
| 3          | 30    | 2015-01-02 |
| 3          | 30    | 2015-01-03 |
```

I want to add together `products.comment_count` + `product_views.count` + `product_likes.count` grouping by `products.id`, where `product_views.pv_date` and `product_likes.pl_date` between `2015-01-01` and `2015-01-03`. Ordering by a `total`.

What I want:

```
| product_id | total |
| -----------|-------|
| 3          | 210   |
| 2          | 140   |
| 1          | 70    |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query

```
SELECT 
   p.product_id, 
  (p.comment_count + SUM(pv.count) + SUM(pl.count)) AS total
 FROM products p
 JOIN products_views pv ON( p.product_id = pv.product_id)
 JOIN products_likes pl ON( p.product_id = pl.product_id)
 WHERE pl.date BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-01-03'
  AND pv.date BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-01-03'
 GROUP BY p.product_id   
 ORDER BY total DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    (products.comment_count+products_views.pv_count+products_likes.pl_count) AS    product_count
    FROM products 
    INNER JOIN products_views.product_id=products.id
    INNER JOIN products_likes.product_id=products.id
    WHERE  (product_views.pv_date BETWEEN dateVal AND dateVal) 
    AND (products_likes.pl_date BETWEEN dateVal AND dateVal) 
   GROUP BY     products.id
   ORDER BY  product_count
```

Answer (score 0):

Perform the counts "per table" before joining otherwise you run the risk of getting larger results than there should be as joins can multiply the number of rows. Also, as there is a chance some products don't exist in likes or views so a left outer join to both of the "derived tables" is recommended.

```
SELECT
      p.product_id
    , (IFNULL(p.comment_count,0) + IFNULL(pv.view_count, 0) + IFNULL(pl.like_count, 0)) AS total
FROM products p
      LEFT OUTER JOIN (
            SELECT
                  product_id
                , SUM(`count`) AS view_count
            FROM products_views
            WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-01-03'
            GROUP BY
                  product_id
      ) pv ON p.product_id = pv.product_id
      LEFT OUTER JOIN (
            SELECT
                  product_id
                , SUM(`count`) AS like_count
            FROM products_likes
            WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-01-03'
            GROUP BY
                  product_id
      ) pl ON p.product_id = pl.product_id
GROUP BY
      p.product_id
ORDER BY
      total DESC
```

btw: `date` and `count` are reserved words in most SQL dialects; it not a good idea to name columns as `date` or `count`; use something more e.g. date_entered, date_created, view_count, like_count etc.

Answer (score -2):

```
select p.product_id, sum(p.comment_count) + sum(v.count) + sum(l.count) as total from products p join products_views v on p.product_id = v.product_id join products_likes l on p.product_id = l.product_id group by p.product_id
where l.date between '2015-01-01' and '2015-01-03'
order by total desc
```

try this

Comment: The query structure is wrong... GROUP BY should be after WHERE